# How to enable HTTP access to Intel RMM3 through ssh console?

Tags: intel

Would you be so kind to write how to enable HTTP access to Intel **RMM3** through **ssh** (SMASH-CLP) console, please?

I have already tried to reset it with a procedure recommended on the Intel forum (https://communities.intel.com/thread/17372?tstart=0)

```
cd /system1/sp1/enetport1/lanendpt1/ipendpt1  
set committed=0  
set committed=1
```

but it didn't solve the problem

Best regards,
Grzegorz

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd /system1/sp1/enetport1/lanendpt1/ipendpt1  
set ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

you can try using the same IP you had before or a different one.

```
set committed=1
```

This worked for me, I changed it to another ip then back again.

This might help: [Intel Remote Management Module 3 - User Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/intel_rmm3_userguide_r1_4.pdf).